# Performance difference Python/Matlab curve fitting

Tags: python, matlab, curve-fitting

When fitting a *very* simple function to some randomly created data I came across the fact that Python seems to outperform Matlab by roughly two orders of magnitude.

Now, this might depend on the specific implementations and also on the function used for this particular fit, however, I still find it strange that there is such a massive difference. I'd be grateful if anybody could tell me how this comes about.

**Matlab** (also used to create data and write to file, which is then read by python):

```
% Write data to file to be able to compare across languages
x = 0:9;
x = repmat(x', 1, 100);
y = x.^2;
y = y+randn(10, 100);
dlmwrite('y_mat.csv',y);
% Fit and time execution
tic
D = zeros(1, 100);
a = zeros(1, 100);
ft = fittype('4*D*x^a');
for i = 1:100
    f = fit(x(:, i),y(:, i), ft);
    a(i) = f.a;
    D(i) = f.D;
end
toc
```

Python:

```
import time
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
start_time = time.time()
data = np.loadtxt("y_mat.csv", delimiter=',');
def func(t, D, a):
    return 4*D*t**a
DA = np.zeros([numParticles, 2])
for i in range(0, numParticles):
    x = np.arange(10) 
    y = data[:,i] 
    popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func, x, y)
    DA[i, ] = popt
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Use `profile` to identify the slow lines of code

Comment: `tic/toc` is very inaccurate for runtime determination. Use [`timeit`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) instead

Comment: A difference in tolerance parameters can greatly influence the runtime: if your `maxfunevals` is 10 times larger, the runtime can be that as well, I'd think. And of course the obvious solution is to just use python;)

Comment: @Adriaan you're right - but timeit disquilaifies itself when it comes to absolute runtimes you'd like to compare with other languaes.

Comment: @thewaywewalk python happens to have [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) (the `ipython` interactive shell: as a magic built-in). That surely counts as something, doesn't it?:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Well, I never know what number `timeit` acutally returns, if you do and you know it's the same as in python, alright.

Comment: @thewaywewalk the docs are rather clear: run the function a couple of times to warm up MATLAB, then execute a couple of times with a tic/toc, then take the median of those times and return that as output.

Comment: Tbh, I think in this case it doesn't really matter which function I use to time the code. In python the code runs 200x faster, and I was wondering whether anyone knows from the top of their head what causes this difference.

Comment: The main difference I see is that you are feeding matlab with some sort of symbolic expression while python is optimizing a numeric one. Create a separate function for Matlab, as you did in Python, and pass the handle to matlab's `fit()`.

Comment: @Oleg you mean doing sth like `ft = fittype(@(D, a, x) 4*D*x.^a, 'independent', {'x'});`? This doesn't make a difference, I  would assume it's pretty much what fit() does internally anyway.

Comment: No, I mean to avoid building the `fittype()` and use a @fun.

Comment: fit needs a fittype, if you provide the anonymous function directly like so `f = fit(x(:, i),y(:, i), @(D, a, x) 4*D*x.^a);`  there is no difference. Except in the first case you save a bit of parsing I guess, cause it doesn't need to figure out what's independent.

Comment: I tried, no difference indeed. I profiled the code and most of the time is spent in `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\toolbox\shared\optimlib\snls.m`. I assume both results from python and Matlab are identical? Then, it's mostly about tweaking some parameters, and yet Matlab might still be slower.